# Angular 7 use ng2-upload Can't not upload file size large 50mb

Tags: angular

When upload file size large 50mb then show error failed net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED. https://gyazo.com/18c928b998fae3a391ad034c695cfdb9.
I have config in php.ini. But request not send to server so not relate upload max size of server.

Comment: please share your code what you trid before?

Comment: I use package https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/